# Ajax update has no effect, Firefox errors: XML or text declaration not at start of entity

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have small form which will receive values from a class. However pressing the button will not update the selectOneMenu.

Refreshing the form will correctly fill the menu with the correct items.

I was expecting

```
update="instrument"/>
```

to refresh the content of the menu. But I guess I am missing something. Note that the method in the bean are getting called on button press. The list is filled and also the int is set when choosing an item.

```
<h:form id="listForm">

            <p:outputLabel for="instrument" value="Instrument " />
            <p:selectOneMenu id="instrument" value="#{tradeFactory.intInstrumentID}" style="width:150px">
                <p:ajax listener="#{tradeFactory.onInstrumentChange(tradeFactory.intInstrumentID)}" update="instrument" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Instrument" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItems value="#{tradeFactory.instrumentID}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
            <p:commandButton value="Update" actionListener="#{tradeFactory.getInstrumentIDs()}" update="instrument"/>
```

Function for update

```
@PostConstruct
public void getInstrumentIDs() {
    Set<Integer> s = trades.keySet();

    instrumentID.clear();

    s.stream().forEach(i -> instrumentID.put(String.valueOf(i), String.valueOf(i)));
}
```

Ajax response body

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response id="j_id1"><changes><update id="growl"><![CDATA[<span id="growl"></span><script id="growl_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw('Growl','widget_growl',{id:'growl',sticky:false,life:5000,escape:true,msgs:[]});});</script>]]></update><update id="listForm:instrument"><![CDATA[<div id="listForm:instrument" class="ui-selectonemenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all" style="width:150px"><div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><input id="listForm:instrument_focus" name="listForm:instrument_focus" type="text" autocomplete="off" /></div><div class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"><select id="listForm:instrument_input" name="listForm:instrument_input" tabindex="-1" onchange="PrimeFaces.ab({s:&quot;listForm:instrument&quot;,e:&quot;valueChange&quot;,f:&quot;listForm&quot;,p:&quot;listForm:instrument&quot;,u:&quot;listForm:instrument&quot;});"><option value="">Select Instrument</option><option value="101" selected="selected">101</option></select></div><label id="listForm:instrument_label" class="ui-selectonemenu-label ui-inputfield ui-corner-all">&nbsp;</label><div class="ui-selectonemenu-trigger ui-state-default ui-corner-right"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s ui-c"></span></div><div id="listForm:instrument_panel" class="ui-selectonemenu-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-helper-hidden ui-shadow"><div class="ui-selectonemenu-items-wrapper" style="height:auto"><ul class="ui-selectonemenu-items ui-selectonemenu-list ui-widget-content ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-helper-reset"><li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="Select Instrument">Select Instrument</li><li class="ui-selectonemenu-item ui-selectonemenu-list-item ui-corner-all" data-label="101">101</li></ul></div></div></div><script id="listForm:instrument_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw("SelectOneMenu","widget_listForm_instrument",{id:"listForm:instrument",widgetVar:"widget_listForm_instrument",behaviors:{valueChange:function(ext) {PrimeFaces.ab({s:"listForm:instrument",e:"valueChange",f:"listForm",p:"listForm:instrument",u:"listForm:instrument"},ext);}}});});</script>]]></update><update id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0"><![CDATA[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]]></update></changes></partial-response>
```

Firefox console

```
15:18:52.737 XML or text declaration not at start of entity1 trades.xhtml:2:1
```

Maven pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.9</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
    <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That `@PostConstruct` introduces a good red herring. To exclude one and other, how does the ajax response look like? (press F12 in browser and open Network tab) Does it contain the updated menu or not? Are there any JS errors in browser's console? (press F12 in browser and open Console tab)

Comment: added network tab. the console is empty

Comment: I gather you're using Chrome. I asked for the ajax response, not for the initiator. Click the ajax request in the Name column (leftmost), then open the Response tab in right section. You just need to tell if it does contain the updated menu or not instead of copypasting the whole thing.

Comment: There is a tab opening automatically when I click request.send but it's just loads of data. is that what you are after?

Comment: Is the updated menu in there or not? (surely you must as being a web developer be capable of reading plain HTML code) This is important to know so we can isolate the cause of the problem.

Comment: And yes it seems like the expected value "101" should be there.

Comment: OK, so server side part works fine. We can now ignore that part. It's just the DOM replacement in client side which failed. It's only strange that there are no JS errors then.

Comment: 15:18:52.737 XML or text declaration not at start of entity1 trades.xhtml:2:1

Comment: The ajax XML response thus contained a double `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>`? It's indeed invalid. Now we have to look back to the server side for the cause as it's the one responsible for producing the XML output. This however indicates a pretty serious bug in either the JSF impl or a messup your webapp's runtime classpath. Can you confirm that webapp's runtime classpath is free of conflicts in JSF API/impl versions? Can you tell which JSF impl/version you're using and if you tried the latest one, if available?

Comment: Using mojarra 2.2. Adding dependencies to question (pom)

Comment: 2.2 is a spec version, not an impl version. There are 2.2.0, 2.2.1, etc.. (currently) 2.2.11.

Comment: It's in the dependencies I added above <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10</version>

Comment: Where's the JSF impl? If you got that to deploy successfully with alone the JSF API, that can only mean that you're deploying to a server which already provides JSF out the box. Which server are you deploying to? A Java EE server like WildFly, TomEE or GlassFish and thus not a barebones serveltcontainer like Tomcat or Jetty?

Comment: It's running at tomcat8

Comment: Where's the JSF impl? Did you manually drop JARs in Tomcat's `/lib` or webapp's `/WEB-INF/lib`?

Comment: No there are none in tomcat8 och web-inf/lib. But adding the impl to the project and indeed setting the right version of jsp-api did the trick. However now I am getting javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: View could not be restored (though everything is working)

Comment: You can in first place not run JSF API without JSF impl. So there's a JSF impl somewhere else in the runtime classpath. JRE or JDK's `/lib` folder?

Comment: This is the only place outside the test app. /home/jocke/.m2/repository/com/sun/faces/jsf-impl/2.2.11/jsf-impl-2.2.11.jar (but since it din't work before I guess it did not exist until I added it into the .pom)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ajax update fail is caused by the double XML prolog in the ajax response:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
```

There may be only one.

This can be caused by a conflict and/or mismatch in JSF API and impl libraries in the runtime classpath. You need to make sure that your runtime classpath is free of conflicts and/or mismatches in API and impl libraries.

Given that you're using Maven and are using a barebones servletcontainer (Tomcat) as target runtime, best way to include the current Mojarra version (2.2.11) is the single `javax.faces.jar` which is available by below coordinate:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.11</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure you remove both `jsf-api` and `jsf-impl` coordinates.