# Ajax not working in JSF 2 application

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm getting errors when trying to refresh the form with `<f:ajax render="@form" listener="#{myBean.onSelectItemChange}" />`

The message in the popup is "emptyResponse: An empty response was received from the server.  Check server error logs."

In Firefox console, the error is "XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity Location"

The same code works well in my local environment. I use Tomcat 9 in both local and production environments. I'm getting errors only in production.

The xhtml page starts with

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets">
```

When rendered, the `<!DOCTYPE html>`is added automatically at the top of the page.

I've also tried adding `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` on the top of the page.

**Edit:** 
To be more specific on error:
XML Parsing Error: XML or text declaration not at start of entity Location: http://serverIP:8080/app/myPage Line Number 2, Column 1:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

**UPDATE:** The XHR response looks like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response>
...
</partial-response>
```

The first line is repeated twice

By the way, the app is working correctly on my development environment. I'm using Tomcat9 on both development(Windows) and production (Ubuntu) computers.

Comment: @mstfdz is right: **there is not** _double quotes_ in the code `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>`

Comment: @Dubois: Sorry, that's utter nonsense. Check [XML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) yourself.

Comment: off-topic: don't mix jsf 2.2 and pre-2.2 namespaces (or maybe it is on-topic)

Comment: you hopefully **know** that firefox gets the **rendered** pages, not the xhtml page. So look what is actually received by the client...

Comment: The received XHR response looks like this: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<partial-response>
...
</partial response> somehow the first line is repeated twice

Comment: So you can improve the title... 'Not working' is to generic. Receiving a duplicate prolog is more explicit. Check if you have duplicate PrimeFaces jars in your project https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340761/ajax-update-has-no-effect-firefox-errors-xml-or-text-declaration-not-at-start

Comment: @Kukeltje your link solved the issue, I've removed the jsf-impl and jsf-api packages and it is working now. Could you post this comment as an answer?

Comment: No  need to, I'll mark it as a duplicate... But remember to read JSF Q/A on stackoverflow about debugging and doing root-cause analysis.... Hmmm I cannot close it since there is a bounty on it... I'll create a short answer then instead

Comment: I've had strange problems like this in the past, and almost always they had something to do with the managed beans and/or converters. Please post the code of your managed bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the client logs this error, the server side XHTML is not to blame or only indirectly. Looking what the real response is in the browswer developer tools will show the real cause.

After you did this it became obvious that there was a 'duplicate' prolog. Using this in a title (or in a search in google) would have most likely pointed to an existing Q/A in in Stackoverflow and effectively making this Q/A a duplicate of it:  [Ajax update has no effect, Firefox errors: XML or text declaration not at start of entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31340761/ajax-update-has-no-effect-firefox-errors-xml-or-text-declaration-not-at-start)

I still post this as an answer for two reasons:

- To show others the relevance of 'root cause analysis'
- It cannot be marked as a duplicate because of the bounty on it

Answer (score -2):

Try to locate the absolute id of your form in the browser using "Inspect elements" then change the render value to this id
you will have something like this :

```
<f:ajax render="element:element1" listener="#{myBean.onSelectItemChange}"></f:ajax>
```

Comment: Care to elaborate on why you think this is needed?

Comment: Thanks @AyoubM, tried it but it is still not working